# Is it advisable to use if-else php code in Yii framework views?

Tags: php, yii, view, renderpartial

I am a noob in Yii framework. I am developing an application without using GII CRUD application. Writing my own models and views from scratch.

I would like to know if it is advisable to use if-else php code in Yii framework views?

Also if to use renderpartial, how to submit data to the controller/model and redirect to the existing page.

I tried reading several blogs and documentation. I looked through YII cookbook as well. But I am unable to find the answer to the first question..

My code is as: http://pastebin.com/BQHJvBcA

Pls help.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using conditional statements in views, as long as it's purely presentational logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Your views would be more clear with it:

Example from php.net:

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a clear direction.. I am just worried from the aspect that it should be readable for the other developers and the best code practice. Because previously when I used smarty, I didnt have to write PHP codes in my tpl files. Was wondering if Yii might have something similar.
Thanks to Lafor too